# Why base64 encode an API authorization key?

Tags: security, api, amazon-web-services, authorization

We're currently designing a web api and are in the process of implementing authorization. We've followed (mostly) [amazons implementation](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RESTAuthentication.html) but there's one part I really don't fully understand.

Namely, what is the point of base64 encoding the resulting hmac? The difference in length is negligible, at least for most sites. Amazon would probably notice the difference though. Is that the only reason? Does it maybe have something to do with ascii/unicode?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Hash algorithms and HMAC don't provide hexadecimal string outputs, which is what many people tend to believe; they both output binary data. Base64 provides you with a way to easily and portably represent binary data as a string.

As far as why, it's likely just for convenience and using a standard encoding between many different parts of their software. There's nothing special about it, other than it being a widely used encoding.

Comment: Implicit in your answer is that API keys need to be passed from clients to servers that typically run RESTful web services and interactions with those are typically over HTTP, which uses strings. So, to pass the API key to such a service over HTTP, you need to encode it somehow and base64 is a popular option for that purpose.

Comment: +1 That's a good example of when it would be better suited to use Base64. I don't do HTTP stuff often, so thanks for adding this.